# Rename all file names in unix shell script

Tags: shell, unix, ksh, mv

I am trying to rename all files in a directory.  For example, these file names:

```
BPP_xxx_xxx-ASTATR_11_xxx_1_1_20180112000002.dat_R52_1
BPP_xxx_xxx-ASTATR_11_xxx_1_1_20180110000000.dat_R52_2
```

Should be renamed to:

```
BPP_xxx_xxx-ASTATR_11_xxx_1_1_20180110111111.dat
BPP_xxx_xxx-ASTATR_11_xxx_1_1_20180111222222.dat
```

Files ending with *R51_1* should have one time stamp, and all files with *R51_2* get another timestamp.   This is the code:

```
#!/bin/ksh
x=$(date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S)
ls -lrt *BACMAIN* | cut -f9,10 -d'_' >tmp.txt
while read LINE; do
x=$(date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S)
filearray=`ls -1t *"$LINE"`
echo "${filearray[@]}"
  for file in "${filearray[@]}"
  do
    mv "$file" "${file%_$LINE}"_$x.dat;
  done
 x=x++;
done < tmp.txt
```

...but am getting an error as below:

```
BPP_xxx_xxx-ASTATR_11_xxx_1_1_20180112000002.dat_R52_1
BPP_xxx_xxx-ASTEVSRC_11_xxx_1_1_20180112000002.dat_R52_1
BPP_xxx_xxx-ASTMAIN_11_xxx_1_1_20180112000002.dat_R52_1
BPP_xxx_xxx-BACBILLDET_12_xxx_1_1_20180112000002.dat_R52_1
BPP_xxx_xxx-BACMAIN_12_xxx_1_1_20180112000002.dat_R52_1
BPP_xxx_xxx-BACPAYDET_12_xxx_1_1_20180112000002.dat_R52_1
mv: accessing `BPP_xxx_xxx-ASTATR_11_xxx_1_1_20180112000002.dat_R52_1\nBPP_xxx_xxx-ASTEVSRC_11_xxx_1_1_20180112000002.dat_R52_1\nBPP_xxx_xxx-ASTMAIN_11_xxx_1_1_20180112000002.dat_R52_1\nBPP_xxx_xxx-BACBILLDET_12_xxx_1_1_20180112000002.dat_R52_1\nBPP_xxx_xxx-BACMAIN_12_xxx_1_1_20180112000002.dat_R52_1\nBPP_xxx_xxx-BACPAYDET_12_xxx_1_1_20180112000002.dat_20180112151217.dat': File name too long
BPP_xxx_xxx-ASTATR_11_xxx_1_1_20180110000000.dat_R52_2
BPP_xxx_xxx-ASTEVSRC_11_xxx_1_1_20180110000000.dat_R52_2
BPP_xxx_xxx-ASTMAIN_11_xxx_1_1_20180110000000.dat_R52_2
BPP_xxx_xxx-BACBILLDET_12_xxx_1_1_20180110000000.dat_R52_2
BPP_xxx_xxx-BACMAIN_12_xxx_1_1_20180110000000.dat_R52_2
BPP_xxx_xxx-BACPAYDET_12_xxx_1_1_20180110000000.dat_R52_2
mv: accessing `BPP_xxx_xxx-ASTATR_11_xxx_1_1_20180110000000.dat_R52_2\nBPP_xxx_xxx-ASTEVSRC_11_xxx_1_1_20180110000000.dat_R52_2\nBPP_xxx_xxx-ASTMAIN_11_xxx_1_1_20180110000000.dat_R52_2\nBPP_xxx_xxx-BACBILLDET_12_xxx_1_1_20180110000000.dat_R52_2\nBPP_xxx_xxx-BACMAIN_12_xxx_1_1_20180110000000.dat_R52_2\nBPP_xxx_xxx-BACPAYDET_12_xxx_1_1_20180110000000.dat_20180112151217.dat': File name too long
```

Comment: I am trying to change the file name with different timestamp e.g. for all files ending with R51_1 with one time stamp and all files with R51_2 with another timestamp.

Comment: Please show a few of the file names before running `mv`, then what they should be renamed to *after* `mv` has run.

Comment: Input File Name :                                                                                         BPP_xxx_xxx-ASTATR_11_xxx_1_1_20180112000002.dat_R52_1
BPP_xxx_xxx-ASTATR_11_xxx_1_1_20180110000000.dat_R52_2        OutPut Should be :                 BPP_xxx_xxx-ASTATR_11_xxx_1_1_20180110111111.dat
BPP_xxx_xxx-ASTATR_11_xxx_1_1_20180111222222.dat

Comment: Given the example `20180112000002` should become `20180110111111`.  Explain why the trailing `12000002` becomes `10111111`.

Comment: This is my project requirement to change the timestamp of the file and then use it ... so I need to do it

Comment: Does it matter at all what the new time stamp is?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163065/discussion-between-agc-and-user1763769).

Comment: sorry not now very much busy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You assign `filearray` a regular string, but then you are using it as an array.

You have to tell the shell, that you want an array

```
typeset -a filearray
```

or

```
filearray=( $(ls -1t *[12]) )
```

For debugging you may put a `echo` in front of `mv` and if you get the desired result, remove it. *Or define `debug=echo`, put `$debug` in front of critical commands. Once done, define `debug=`*

For some more improvements put the code in https://www.shellcheck.net/, and take care of line 12.